# Parallel assignment with parentheses and splat operator

Tags: ruby, parallel-assignment

I got this:

```
x,(y,z)=1,*[2,3]

x # => 1
y # => 2
z # => nil
```

I want to know why `z` has the value `nil`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
x, (y, z) = 1, *[2, 3]
```

The splat `*` on the right side is expanded inline, so it's equivalent to:

```
x, (y, z) = 1, 2, 3
```

The parenthesized list on the left side is treated as nested assignment, so it's equivalent to:

```
x = 1
y, z = 2
```

`3` is discarded, while `z` gets assigned to `nil`.

Comment: Good answer. And if `x, (y, z), u = 1, *[2, 3]` then `x #=> 1; y #=> 2; z #=> nil;  u #=> 3`.

Comment: Ok so splat has precedence over parantheses and the parantheses treat values in them as a single unit

Comment: I don't think precedence is relevant here, as the parenthesis and splat are on opposite sides of the equality. The key is Yu's statement, "The splat `*` on the right side...". Parallel assignment causes `x` to be set equal to `1`, `(y,z)` set equal to `2` and so on, and if `(y,z) = 2`, then `y #=> 2; z #=> nil`.